# Advice on self study of category theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, category-theory, book-recommendation, reference-works

I'm very intrested in start to study category theory with aim to use this in algebraic geometry. I already took courses (besides the basics) on commutative algebra and general topology with a soft introduction to algebraic topology. But I don't know any references in category theory. Can someone give some idea for what book or lecture notes I can get a introduction on this topic?

Thank you so much in any advance!

Comment: "Categories for the working mathematician" may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Here's a good [list of references](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/bib.html). You may also read the [accompanying article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found [*Category Theory*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199237182) by Steve Awodey to be a really good introduction to the subject. It doesn't lead directly into algebraic geometry (or, indeed, in any particular direction), but gives a readable introduction to the subject with plenty of examples and problems. When you've worked through this you could move on to a more advanced text or one which is more specifically geared towards algebraic geometry.

On the side, I'll mention [Ravi Vakil's epic notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/) on algebraic geometry which kick off with category theory before moving on.

Comment: Thank you !! I think both will help me a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to learn the basics of category theory is to see it in action. For this reason, I recommend Rotman's [*An Introduction to Homological Algebra*](http://books.google.ca/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Homological_Algebra.html?id=P2HV4f8gyCgC&redir_esc=y), but you have to be algebra-inclined.

Comment: I've heard about this, Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

You can also take a look at this wonderful set of [video lectures](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/Edsko.de.Vries/ct/catsters/linear.php) by Eugenia Cheng

Comment: That link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 4):

You could try Gelfand and Manin's Methods of Homological Algebra - it introduces a lot of category theory (the whole thing is really an intro to derived categories) from scratch, and homological algebra is a big part of algebraic geometry. Their examples are more topological than geometric though.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite book is "Categories and Sheaves" by Kashiwara and Schapira. For a more introductory approach you can pick "Abstract and Concrete Categories: The Joy of Cats" by Adamek, Herrlich and Strecker (I think that there is a free online version of this book at the site of some of the authors) .

Answer (score 4):

The trilogy of Francis Borceux "Handbook of categorical algebra", the first volume is a nice introduction.