# Category theory book

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation

I have learnt Algebrac Topology for some months . I learn by myself without teacher and I realize I need more knowledge at Algebra, Homology and Category theory . I just knew a book of Maclane but I am not interested in his style and want to some book which write brief ( enough to use ) . Could someone recommend me some books at Category theory .

Comment: See also [Which books to study category theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517109/which-books-to-study-category-theory?rq=1)

Comment: The duplicate listed (first comment below your question) currently has 26 answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Category theory in context](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf) by
Emily Riehl or [Abstract and Concrete Categories, The Joy of Cats](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf) by J. Adamek,
H. Herrlich and G. E. Strecker.

Answer (score 1):

The first volume of Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra* is also quite a good book. My only caveat to it as a category theory intro is that monads tend to appear in most introductory texts, but Borceux defers them until volume 2; otherwise it's nicely thorough.